# Android: Remove Button Press Highlight on Disable

Tags: android, button, state

I've just spent 3 days finishing up a bunch of threading around handling NFC tag commands and tag removal from the phone only to be stumped by what should be a very simple thing.

If the user has a button (for a tag command) pressed and thus highlighted then removes the tag the command button needs to be disabled and is but the highlight color on the button remains indefinitely even when re-enabled.

How do I force the button to the non pressed background color even when the user is pressing the button on button disable?

Why doesn't this work?

```
mTagStartCommandButton.setSelected(false);
mTagStartCommandButton.setEnabled(false);
```

I've looked into StateListDrawable and the like but I don't need to define a new state just get the button into the correct state before disable.

Thanks, Sand

Answer (score 0):

try requesting focus to some other view. May be next button or edit box.